# Database design for recurring events with exceptions

Tags: sql, database, database-design, calendar, recurring-events

I'm building a system that needs to store/manage different types of events. For simplicity, I will focus on designing a calendar (I'm building something slightly different, but calendar is a good analogy and it's easy to reason about). I'd like to hear about possible database/schema design ideas.

**Problem Description**

I have a calendar with different types of events (for simplicity sake, say there is only 1 type of event: Task). User can add new event for a particular date, edit (change some details, like title or move to another date) or delete. There can be one-time events and recurring events (with different types of recurrence: every X days, every 15th day of the month, every week on Monday; kind of like simple cron). When user moves recurring event, all other instances of this event are moved in the same manner (e.g: +3 days). Important part: recurring events can have exceptions. So, for example, let's say I have an recurring event A which is repeated every 7 days. But I want to change it's date for next week, so instead of Tuesday, it's be assigned to Friday, after that it'll still occur on Tuesday. This "exception" event shouldn't be affected when "parent" event is moved.

Also, every recurring event can have additional info, that is related only to 1 particular instance, e.g: I have the same recurring event A repeated every 7 days, I want to add a note for this week instance that says "X", and I want to add another note for the event A next month that says "Y" - those fields are only visible to that single instances.

**Ideas**

System with regular, one-time events is pretty straightforward so I won't discuss that and focus only on recurring events.

**1.** One possible solution is the one that resembles OOP: I can have an `Event` "class" with fields such as `start_date`, `end_date` (can be `null`), `recurrence_type` (something like enum with possible values of `EVERY_X_DAYS`, `DAY_OF_WEEK`, `DAY_OF_MONTH`) and `recurrence_value` (say `7`). When user adds new recurring event, I just create such `Event` in the database. When user wants to change 1 occurrence of this event, I add new entry to the DB of the type/class `MovedEvent` that "inherits" from `Event` with different date and has additional field `related_to` that points to the `ID` (or `UUID`, if you will) of the `Event` that it's related to. But at the same time, I need to keep track of all the `MovedEvent`s (otherwise I'd have 2 events displayed in the same week), so I need to have an array `moved_events` of `ID`s that point to all `MovedEvent`s.
**Disadvantage**: every time I want to display the calendar I need to get `Event` and select all events from the `moved_events`, which is not optimal if I'll have a lot of moved events.

**2.** Another idea is to store every event as a separate record. IMO it's a terrible idea, but I just mentioning it because it's a possibility. **Disadvantages**: every time I want to edit the main event (e.g: I want to change the event from occurring "every 7 days" to "every 9 days") I need to change every single occurrence of the event. "Exceptions" (changing single instance) is easier, though.

**SQL/NoSQL? Scale details**

I'm using PostgreSQL in my project, but I have basic knowledge in NoSQL databases and if they are better suited for this kind of a problem, I can use it.

Scale: Let's say I have 5k users, and each will have on average 150 events/week, 40% of which can be "exceptions". Therefore I want to design this system to be efficient.

**Similar Questions & Other Resources**

I've just started reading Martin Fowler's "Recurring Events for Calendars" (http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/recurring.pdf) but I'm not sure if it applies to my problem and if so, how one would design database schema according to this document (suggestions are welcome).

There are similar questions, but I didn't see any mention of "exceptions" (changing 1 event instance without affecting other), but maybe someone will find these links useful:

- [Design question: How would you design a recurring event system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123793/design-question-how-would-you-design-a-recurring-event-system)
- [Optimal design for a Database with recurring event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634699/optimal-design-for-a-database-with-recurring-event)
- [Design option for 'recurring tasks'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412527/design-option-for-recurring-tasks)
- [Calendar Recurring/Repeating Events - Best Storage Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183630/calendar-recurring-repeating-events-best-storage-method)
- [What is the best way to represent "Recurring Events" in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579638/what-is-the-best-way-to-represent-recurring-events-in-database)

Sorry for a long question, I wanted to describe the problem well. Yet, I feel that's pretty chaotic, so if you have additional questions, I will happily provide more details. Again, I'd like to hear about possible database/schema design ideas plus any other suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: hey can share your experience how you ended up implementing this or  few tips  for implementation.

Comment: Hello, I'm dealing with this issue as well. I've decided to go with the blunt solution of separate event entries for each repeated occurrence. My events system has activity like RSVPs, payments and comments separately for each event occurrence, and each event occurrence must have it's own unique event id, highest priority. This alone makes my choice easy, I have to store each event separately. On the plus side, my user base activity occurs only a few months at a time, so I can make an auto-expiry rule (e.g. 3 months max) which will keep DB processing times manageable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [iCalendar](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) RRules and ExDates

If it's a recurring event, just store the start/end datetimes and RRules and ExDates for the event.

Use a Materialized View to pre-calculate upcoming actual events, say for the next 30 days or 365 days.

As you are using Postgres, you can use existing python, perl, or javascript RRule libraries (such as [dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57)) inside pg function for calculating future events based on the rrules and exdates

UPDATE: check out pg_rrule extension: https://github.com/petropavel13/pg_rrule

Comment: ExRules are deprecated in RFC 5455 (the one linked). ExDates are now used to create exceptions to RRules. ExDate, however, is not supported by pg_rrule as of this comment. [There's an open issue on this](https://github.com/petropavel13/pg_rrule/issues/3)

Comment: I'm coming across your comment 4 years later and man, I wish I had found it two weeks ago.